# Jade Not Executing Inline onClick Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am completely new to Jade and trying to get a simple inline button click to throw up an alert.

I have layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    block content
```

Then in index.jade I have

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  p Adam

  input(type="text", id="wordToChange")
  input(type="text", id="wordToChangeToo")
  button(type="submit", onClick="javascript:alert('Adam!!')")
```

I've tried several variations of the alert line.  Ideas?

Html that is generated.

```
<head>
    <title>Adam</title>
    <link href="/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
    <body>

        <p>Welcome to Adam</p>
        <p>Adam</p>
        <input id="wordToChange" type="text">
            <input id="wordToChangeToo" type="text">
                <button onclick="javascript:alert('Adam!!')" type="submit"></button>
```

UPDATE:  Apparently it's limited to IE?  It works and alerts in FF.  Must be a support issue in IE.

Comment: what is the html that is generated?

Comment: How do you know that click is not working?. Where is the text for button btw?

Comment: So technically it is working...just was in IE on a build server...as soon as I switched to FF it worked...

Comment: When I open the html file with Internet Explorer 8.0, I get a warning: "To help protect your security, Internet Explorer has restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls that could access your computer. Click here for options...". I then click on the bar to "Allow Blocked Content..." and click the Yes button on the confirmation dialog box. The html works now.

Comment: @bnuhero you are correct, it was security settings in IE causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is...security settings.  The IE I was using had security settings on high that disabled JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the HTML to Jade converter: http://html2jade.aaron-powell.com/

I had the same exact problem you're having, and the converter helped me solved my problems.

Answer (score -1):

The string you pass to `onclick` will be `eval`'d, essentially.  `javascript:alert('Adam!!')` isn't valid JavaScript.

Have you tried `button(type="submit", onClick="alert('Adam!!')")` in your Jade, which should render to `<button onclick="javascript:alert('Adam!!')" type="submit"></button>`?

You'll also likely want something *inside* of your button so that you can see it better.

Comment: `javascript:alert('Adam!!')` **is** a valid javascript, where first part is a label

Comment: Touché.  You're absolutely right, and I swear I tested it with the `javascript:` part in there and it didn't work.  I'm obviously wrong about that.  I'm down-voting my answer because it's incorrect.  Is deleting the write thing to do here?  The bit about text inside the button might be useful, but the rest of the answer is not.  UPDATE: I can't down-vote my own answer.

Comment: there, I fixed it for you :P